# Latex table with multiple multirows

Tags: tables, multirow

Could you guys please help me on how to produce a table like this one in Overleaf using ieeetran template?

I can't figure out how to create the multiple \multirow.

Best regards!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! What you try so far? There on site are plenty  similar  questions and answers about tables. I suggest you to search for them.

Answer (score 1):

I guess for `\multirow` the same format should work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c | c | c}
\toprule
Column1 & Column2 & Column3 \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{Common1} & A1 & B1 \\
                    \cline{2-3}
                         & C1 & D1\\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{Common2} & A2 & B2 \\
                    \cline{2-3}
                         & C2 & D2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is this the similar multirow output you seek?

[image: Test_Table]

Comment: Thank you for the help. This \cline command is what I was missing!